# Error 91 vba excel random

Tags: vba, excel

I was working on my first vba script to automate some stuff within Excel.
The code was working fine but suddenly sometimes I get an

> error 91

on the line

`zoeken.select`

```
Sub kopieermacro()    

    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim zoeken As Worksheet        

     ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E18,N2:N18,O2:O18").Copy        

     a = Worksheets("Berekenen").OLEObjects("cmbsheet").Object.Value
     Sheets(a).Activate
     Set zoeken = Sheets(a).Cells.Find(What:=DateValue(InputBox("voer datum in")))
     zoeken.Select

     ActiveCell.Offset(rowoffset:=2, columnoffset:=0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With the line:

```
Set zoeken = Sheets(a).Cells.Find(What:=DateValue(InputBox("voer datum in")))
```

you are setting `zoeken` to the date from the input box within `Sheets(a)`. It can be, that this date does not exist, thus you need to make a check, before the `.Select`:

```
Set zoeken = Sheets(a).Cells.Find(What:=DateValue(InputBox("voer datum in")))
If Not zoeken Is Nothing Then
    zoeken.Select
Else
    MsgBox "Zoeken is Nothing"
End If
```